# Como posso obter um trecho especifico dentro de uma string usando PHP?

Tags: php

Essas são minhas strings:

```
"banner_2_0_.jpeg",
"banner_2_1_.jpeg",
"banner_2_2_.jpeg", 
"banner_2_3_.jpeg"
```

Eu queria obter o número que estar variando

Comment: vc quer por exemplo `20` ou `2_0`

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma de obter diretamente o valor, sem precisar trabalhar novamente com o retorno é utilizar a função [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
function getNumberFromFilename ($filename): int
{
  preg_match_all("/_(\d+)/", $filename, $matches);

  return $matches[1][1];
}
```

A função `preg_match_all` possui os seguintes parâmetros:

```
int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Ou seja, busque em `$filename` os valores que correspondem à expressão `/\d+/` e armazene-os em `$matches`. Após, retorne a segunda ocorrência (índice 1), da segunda combinação (índice 1) de `$matches`. Desta forma, tem-se:

```
> echo getNumberFromFilename("banner_2_0_.jpeg");
0
```

> Você pode ver o código funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fbe7/1) com toda a lista de arquivos dada no enunciado.

---

**Nota**: editei a resposta incluindo na expressão regular o caractere `_`. Desta forma, o código funcionará também para padrões com caracteres numéricos na primeira parte, tais como `banner5_2_5.jpeg`, pois somente analisará os números que são precedidos de `_`. Embora ainda exista a limitação de não poder ter o caractere `_` seguido de um número na primeira parte, tal como `ban_2ner_3_0.jpeg`, o que é improvável acontecer.

Comment: Boa resposta, além de tudo se os nomes dos arquivos mudarem, mas manterem os números a função continuará funcionando! Parabéns!

Answer (score 1):

Com expressões regulares.
Sem enrolação aqui vai uma expressão regular:

```
<?php

(?:banner[\_]([0-9]+)[\_]([0-9]+)[\_][\.](?:jpeg|jpg))

?>
```

Ela aceita:
banner_2_1_.jpeg
ou
banner_2_1_.jpg

Ela analisa e exige que o nome da imagem seja 'banner_x_x_.jpeg ou banner_x_x_.jpg'

Ela retorna duas variáveis. Bem eu fiz isso porque pode permitir fazer algo mais se quiser.
Na variável $1 ela retorna o primeiro número.
Na variável $2 ela retorna o segundo número.
Agora só analisar as variáveis e fazer o que quiser. A regex foi testada e qualquer coisa que não seja exatamente 'banner_xxxxx_xxxx_.jpeg' ou 'banner_xxxxx_xxxx_.jpg' é ignorado e retorna NULL nas duas variáveis.

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Função Explode: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php
Função Count: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php

a grosso modo, tudo que não é banner e .jpg são seus numeros.

Logo poderíamos fazer:

```php
<?php
// Sua variavel
$variavel = "banner_2_0_.jpeg";

// A função explode ele transforma uma string em um arraylist
// ou seja, ao passar o delimitador, ele irá dar um push em 
// toda a palavra que estiver até antes do delimitador, que no
/// nosso caso foi o "_"**/
$array= explode("_",trim($variavel));

// array que receberá somente os numeros
$newArray = array();

// dar um for de acordo com a quantidade de posições
// criadas no array
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

   // como já sabemos que começa com banner e termina com jpeg
   // tudo que não for isso, será nossos numeros
   if ($array[i] !== 'banner' || $array[i] !== '.jpeg')
   {
      // popula o novo array com somente os numeros
      array_push($array[i],$newArray);
   }
}

//imprime o array
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Um jeito diferente usando `preg_replace`:

```
$string = "banner_2_0_.jpeg";

$result = preg_replace('/.*_(\d+)_(\d+)_\..*$/', "$2", $string);

print_r($result); // Result: 0
```

Procuro de trás pra frente um ou mais números seguidos de underline e ponto: `(\d+)_(\d+)_\..*$/` e completo com o restante da string para poder substituir tudo: `/.*_`, o `$2` é valor do segundo `(\d+)` que é o número que você precisa e que será atribuído ao `$result`.

Se você quiser juntar os 2 números poderá usar: `$1$2` ao invés de só `$2`.